# JavaScript does not find object BigInteger

Tags: javascript, biginteger

This is the first time I am trying to write javaScript.

I have copied this code from the Internet

```
var polynomial = function( x ){
alert(x);
    x = new BigInteger( x.toString,10);
    var y = new BigInteger( coefficients[0].toString, 10 );
    for( var i = 1; i < k; i++ ){
        y = y.add( coefficients[i].multiply( x.pow( i ) ) );
    }
    return y;
};
```

However I get an error at the line

```
x = new BigInteger( x.toString,10);
```

and I do not know why...

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please give the specific error.

Comment: Seems like you need the BigInteger library. Google must have the info.

Comment: I have found how to see the errors from the browser.

Comment: The error is "BigInteger is not defined".

Comment: Copying code without much idea of what it is/does is not a good way to learn.

Comment: I do not want to learn javascript right now. I just have to use this small piece of code at a system I am writing, and I have this error :)

Comment: See the comment by elclanrs above. The code you have depends on an external library, you have to download it and link it from your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other people have pointed out, `BigInteger` is not built-in to JavaScript. I searched for a `Big­Int­eger` library in JavaScript and found [this](http://xenon.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/). To use that, you need to download `jsbn.js` and `jsbn2.js` from that website and add these `script` tags *above* the `script` tag including your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsbn.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsbn2.js"></script>
```

Additionally, as others have pointed out, you are missing parentheses on the `toString`s.

Together, your HTML might look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsbn.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsbn2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var polynomial = function(x) {
        x = new BigInteger( x.toString(), 10 );
        var y = new BigInteger( coefficients[0].toString(), 10 );
        for( var i = 1; i < k; i++ ){
            y = y.add( coefficients[i].multiply( x.pow( i ) ) );
        }
        return y;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, and especially your KIND help :) It is working, and I have accepted the answer.

Comment: Now I have the right reputation, I also vote your answer up :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the toString method!

```
x.toString()
```

The browser has a console, use F12

And it sounds like you did not include the library. https://github.com/silentmatt/javascript-biginteger/blob/master/biginteger.js

Comment: Thank you very much. However the error is about the BigInteger.. "BigInteger is not defined "

Comment: No where in your comment you mentioned the error was about BigInteger.  I saw the error and posted it. Thanks for the downvote. lol Your problem is  probably you did not include the library, but since you did not include the actual error, who would have known that?

Comment: I did not downvoted you :) I tried to upvote you, but I do not have the reputation needed to upvote you :)

Comment: I did not know what the error was, until you posted about F12. Thats the way I found about the error, and thank you very much about that

Comment: Now I have the right reputation, I also vote your answer up :)

Answer (score 0):

The BigInteger is not 1 of javascript types, I think that this part of code needs you to import a js framework, not sure what it is. Ｙou should check where you copy the code.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have right. I also vote your answer up :)